# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in scala spark function in dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

good afternoon. I find myself working with scala functions for datasets, in particular with a sequence between two dates with an interval of one day, the dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:000", this with an interval of one day.

```
Dataset<Row> currentLetters = currentLettersDataset
                .withColumn("range_dates",
                        functions.sequence(functions.col("start_date"), functions.col("end_date")));
```

The problem is that for certain dates I am getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when applying said sequence

The dataset I'm currently working is this

[image]

And the exception is

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 135
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can see the relation of the index with the days between the dates, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: This works just fine (both with timestamps and dates), are you sure the error is not occurring somewhere else? Can you post the rest of the code possibly?

Comment: I'm sure, I put shows for datasets in all the flow of the program and the sequence function throws the exception. I put that range of dates manually in database to force the exception to ocurre. Befor that instruccion its just the recolection of the data.

Comment: Any update on this @JuanDanielCortezRojas? I may have the same issue